# Nested ListBox: is it possible to recover the parent ListBox item when a child ListBox item is selected?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, nested

I have a nested ListBoxes like a warningListBox item that can contain a picturesListBox and a audioRecordListBox. 
When I select one element of a child ListBox (es. item of pictureListBox), I need not only to recover the selected picture item but also the item of the parent warning ListBox (item of the warningListBox).
In the multimediaListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) I can recover the child item selected

((System.Windows.Controls.ListBox)sender).SelectedItem

but HOW CAN I RECOVER THE ITEM of the PARENT warningListBox??

Must I add in each ListBox child element an additional field with the id of the parent item?? ... or there is a better solution, for example navigating in the sender or using the eventArgs of the SelectionChanged event?

Waiting for some suggestions ...

Enzo Contini

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest to make the data structure similar to the UI you have. So make the data structure nested too.

To enable tracing the parent, add a Parent property to the child items.

This way you can get the parent item like this:

```
var parent = ((MySubitem)((System.Windows.Controls.ListBox)sender).SelectedItem).Parent;
```

You might find it easier to maintain this structure than to try and trace the UI controls.

Comment: Thank you Erno. 
I have already a data source that reflects the nested structure:

public class AttachmentsPivotDataSource {
private SignallingList _warningSignallingList;
        public SignallingList WarningSignallingList { //per PivotItem Name="WarningsPivotItem"
            get {
                return _warningSignallingList;
            }
            set {
                _warningSignallingList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("WarningSignallingList");
            }
        }
...